# show $g(p,q)=(1 − p)\log_2 (\frac{ 1 − p}{1 − q}) + p\log_2(\frac{p}{q}) − \frac{2}{\ln(2)}(p − q)^2\ge 0$ for $p,q\in[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Show $g(p,q)=(1 − p)\log_2 (\frac{ 1 − p}{1 − q})  + p\log_2(\frac{p}{q}) − \frac{2}{\ln(2)}(p − q)^2\ge 0$  for $p,q\in[0,1]$

I saw the following explanation, but I don't really understand it:

> It follows that $dg/dq \le 0$ if $p \ge q$ and $dg/dq \ge 0$
> otherwise. Notice that $g(p, q) = 0$ at $p = q$. So $g(p, q) \ge 0$,
> which implies the desired inequality

I don't understand this conclusion

> So $g(p, q) \ge 0$, which implies the desired inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that that the function $g$ becomes zero **only and only when** $p=q$.
Starting with $p=q$, if you change the value of  $p$ and $q$ in any way, the value of $g$ is only going to increase, so that you will never get  $g<0$ ever.
e.g. if you keep $p$ constant and start decreasing $q$, the value of $g$ will increase (as $\frac{dg}{dq} <0$).Thus it will never be zero again (nor will it be less than that ever). Similarly check for the other case.